# Evaluating the model as you train with scikit's LatentDirichletAllocation class

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning, lda

I am experimenting with the [LatentDirichletAllocation() class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html) in scikit-learn, and the `evaluate_every` parameter has the following description.

> How often to evaluate perplexity. Only used in fit method. set it to 0
>   or negative number to not evalute perplexity in training at all.
>   Evaluating perplexity can help you check convergence in training
>   process, but it will also increase total training time. Evaluating
>   perplexity in every iteration might increase training time up to
>   two-fold.

I set this parameter to 2 (default is 0) and saw an increased training time, but I can't seem to find the perplexity values anywhere. Are these results saved, or are they only used by the model to determine when to stop? I was hoping to use the perplexity values to measure the progress and learning curve of my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used in conjunction with the `perp_tol` parameter to assess convergence, and is not saved between iterations, per the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py#L530):

```
for i in xrange(max_iter):

    # ...

    # check perplexity
    if evaluate_every > 0 and (i + 1) % evaluate_every == 0:
        doc_topics_distr, _ = self._e_step(X, cal_sstats=False,
                                            random_init=False,
                                            parallel=parallel)
        bound = self.perplexity(X, doc_topics_distr,
                                sub_sampling=False)
        if self.verbose:
            print('iteration: %d, perplexity: %.4f'
                    % (i + 1, bound))

        if last_bound and abs(last_bound - bound) < self.perp_tol:
            break
        last_bound = bound
    self.n_iter_ += 1
```

Note though that you could easily adapt the existing source to do this by (1) adding the line `self.saved_bounds = []` to the `__init__` method (2) adding `self.bounds.append(bound)` to the above, like so:

```
if last_bound and abs(last_bound - bound) < self.perp_tol:
    break
last_bound = bound
self.bounds.append(bound)
```

Depending on where you saved your updated class, you'd also have to adapt the imports at top of file to reference full module paths in scikit-learn.